# Edit field and append value to a python dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
123     name    test
234     rest    check
```

I require the following to happen

```
Col1        Col2    Col3
test-123    name    test
test-234    rest    check
```

Add "`test-`" to the value in `Col1` of the data frame

Answer (score 0):

Convert numeric to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and add string:

```
df['Col1'] = 'test-' + df['Col1'].astype(str)
print (df)

       Col1  Col2   Col3
0  test-123  Name   addr
1  test-234  test  first
```

Another solution:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply('test-{}'.format)
print (df)
       Col1  Col2   Col3
0  test-123  Name   addr
1  test-234  test  first
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [359]: %timeit 'test-' + df['Col1'].astype(str)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.4 ms per loop

In [360]: %timeit df['Col1'].apply('test-{}'.format)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.66 ms per loop
```

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: df['Col1'] = 'test-' + df['Col1'].astype(str)

Comment: Yes, both solution working very well. But second solution is faster.